# Image preview in vim

Tags: terminal, vim, images, pictures

Is there a way to preview images in neovim? There is a feature like this in ranger (im using alacritty btw). I want to preview the image in vim insted of showing the text version of it. I think ranger is using w3m to show the images.
[image: Ranger Image preview]

Comment: graphics, if any, is a feature of the terminal and therefore you must at least run in a supported terminal

Comment: I know and alacritty supports graphics

Comment: Is there a way to get vim to display images the same way ranger does in alacritty?